# Why does Visual studio 2019 adds <TypeScriptCompile Remove /> in my project?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core 2.2 project running on .net 4.7.2, which includes the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild nuget package.

Every time I add a new typescript (.ts or .tsx) file to my project, visual studio automatically adds a:

```
<ItemGroup><TypeScriptCompile Remove="myFile.ts" /></ItemGroup>
```

line into my project .csproj file.

Here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Target latest version of ECMAScript.
    "target": "esnext",

    // Search under node_modules for non-relative imports.
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    // Process & infer types from .js files.
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",

    // Don't emit; allow Babel to transform files.
    "noEmit": true,

    // Enable strictest settings like strictNullChecks & noImplicitAny.
    "strict": true,

    // Disallow features that require cross-file information for emit.
    "isolatedModules": true,

    // Import non-ES modules as default imports.
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        /* my paths */
    }
  },
  "include": [
        /* my typescript folders */
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Note that I'm only using the package to type-check my files, the actual compilation is done using Babel.

Can you please help me understand why Visual studio adds these TypeScriptCompile Remove in my project? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Whats your project structure? I'd assume you put the ts file in the project root or somewhere outside your tsconfig folder and you're not using the spa template? The SPA templates have something along the lines of `<SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>` and `<Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />` and then use targets to compile it / run the angular-cli or npm scripts or webpack to compile it or start an npm process which does the stuff necessary for hot module replacement (when debugging) or build static files when publish

Comment: Hello @Tseng, my .ts files are in the "include" folders from the tsconfig file.
Regarding the SPA templates I think this is different, they use .netapp with spa services while I'm using .net472 with TypeScript.MSBuild to build typescript.

Comment: For Visual Studio and .NET Core the tsconfig isn't really evaluated when you add files or not, thats only for the TypeScript compiler. The default project templates exclude content from the SPA folder, thats why files created there won't be added to csproj, which is why I asked for your project structure

Comment: I did a test on a SPA template: as soon as I add the Typescript.MSBuild nuget package, visual studio starts adding Removes, even in the SpaRoot: <TypeScriptCompile Remove="ClientApp\myTestFile.ts" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "remove" entry is added so that you don't get the nested filename.js and filename.js.map files appearing in your project folder structure. The instruction explicitly tells Visual Studio not to compile this file and instead allows you to use some other compiler (either the TSC that you downloaded via NPM or perhaps even the Angular compiler). Basically it tells VisualStudio to get out of the way.

Comment: My VS2019 never generated any .js or .map file even without that configuration. I'm using a bundler (webpack). From your answer, and since this behaviour stopped when I switched that project's framework to netcore, it probably was a legacy behaviour. Thanks for your time!